# " No module named 'vlc' " - trouble importing VLC with Python

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I am trying to use the python-vlc library in python and keep getting errors when using "import vlc".

I have the 64-bit Windows version of VLC player installed, and am using Python version 3.9.6 in a virtual environment in Visual Studio. My version of Windows is also 64-bit.

I used "pip install python-vlc" to download the module from the terminal within the project's virtual environment and confirmed that it downloaded correctly.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
try:
    import vlc
except:
    from os import environ
    vlc_path = 'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC'
    environ['PATH'] += ';' + vlc_path
    import vlc
```

When running this in Visual Studio I get the error:

```
No module named 'vlc'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are there supposed to be spaces in file directory names?

Comment: @thirdsandfourths are you referring to the space in "Program Files" (i.e. "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC") ? That's how the directory path appears in my windows browser and how I've seen this code suggested in other threads. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Did you choose the correct virtual environment in VS code?  Maybe [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) helps

Comment: should it be pip3 install python-vlc

Comment: @suvayu now that you mention it, when I inspect the directory: "project\env\Lib\site-packages" (which is where I assume the downloaded package (python-vlc) should be, I don't see it there. But when I downloaded (pip install python-vlc) via the terminal, I confirmed that the command line was launching from the correct env.

Comment: Can you import it in the Python REPL in the terminal?  If you can, then look for the `vlc.__file__` attribute.  That should tell you where it is installed.

Comment: @ScottHJ Yes and what I mean is that the space might cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install library locally by doing `pip install -t . python-vlc --no-user` and try to import it (you will download a vlc.py file to your project folder and you can try to import it)

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I'm now having trouble with my first implementation --playing a video file-- but at least "import vlc" seems to be working now. Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as solution please? This way I can get some karma