# How to play a MP4 video inside tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, video

I am trying to play an MP4 video inside Tkinter, I've tried using a module called "tkvideo", everything worked just fine until I resized the video, the video started playing in slow motion. It seems that the author is aware of [this bug](https://github.com/huskeee/tkvideo/issues/1) but they don't know how to resolve the issue, as this was a side-project for their former university assignment. It seems that the video speed depends on the resolution. Does anyone know any other way to play a video inside of Tkinter? I've searched everywhere, but nothing I found worked for me.

I'm using Windows 10 with Python 3.9.

Comment: it's gonna be pretty hard because `tkinter` is slow, you can try out `cv` library and somehow combine it with `tkinter`, otherwise not much you can do

Comment: You can try an example [tkvlc.py](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/tkvlc.py) using `vlc`.

Comment: And if you have trouble installing `vlc`, see [" No module named 'vlc' " - trouble importing VLC with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68967074/16775594).

Comment: That said, using `tkinter` with `vlc` is an okay solution, but I recommend using a different toolkit, like PyQt or Gtk. For example, Flowblade is a very capable movie editor, and it uses Python Gtk! (and no, I am not affiliated with Flowblade; I just looked at its source code ;-)).

Comment: Use tkvideoplayer module